# Why do rapid clicks on button calls click event multiple times in .Net MAUI?

Tags: maui

I am Navigating to a new page in the application using the following line of code:

```
  await Shell.Current.Navigation.PushAsync(new MyAccountsTabbedPage(_accountsViewModel, tcode, _supportPageViewModel, _contactusPageViewModel, _faqCategoryPageViewModel));
```

Navigation on button clicks causes multiple pages to open all at once if the button is pressed rapidly multiple times, resulting in poor user experience.

We can avoid it by applying the following check on Navigation stack before navigating to the particular page:

```
if (Shell.Current.Navigation.NavigationStack.Count == 0 || Shell.Current.Navigation.NavigationStack.Last().GetType() != typeof(MyAccountsTabbedPage))
            await Shell.Current.Navigation.PushAsync(new MyAccountsTabbedPage(_accountsViewModel, tcode, _supportPageViewModel, _contactusPageViewModel, _faqCategoryPageViewModel));
```

OR, by using logic on isEnabled in button (doesn't sound to be a good approach).

Refer to the following code on button click:

```
private async void ViewStatements_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  var button = (Button) sender;
  _accountsViewModel.SelectedLease = (LeaseInfo) button.CommandParameter;
  string tcode = _accountsViewModel.SelectedLease.TenantCode;
  await _accountsViewModel.IsServiceChargeVisible(tcode);
  if (Shell.Current.Navigation.NavigationStack.Count == 0 || Shell.Current.Navigation.NavigationStack.Last().GetType() != typeof (MyAccountsTabbedPage))
    await Shell.Current.Navigation.PushAsync(new MyAccountsTabbedPage(_accountsViewModel, tcode, _supportPageViewModel, _contactusPageViewModel, _faqCategoryPageViewModel));

}
```

This doesn't seem to be a good approach, is there a better way of doing this or a better approach to do navigation to avoid it?

In case, the user presses the button multiple times to navigate to a certain screen, the behavior should be same as single click.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably experiencing this issue because you're `await`ing code between the event raised by the button click and the `PushAsync` instruction. This results in a delay navigating to the new page.

You could call this line

```cs
  await _accountsViewModel.IsServiceChargeVisible(tcode);
```

somewhere else (maybe in the initialization of `MyAccountsTabbedPage`?).

Otherwise, if you need to call it exactly when you press the button, you could use `isEnabled` as you suggested (it's not necessarily a bad practice) and show an [`ActivityIndicator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/activityindicator).

Comment: Disabling the button is not only not a bad practice, is a very common good aproach! User clicks, webpage disables button and shows some animation while the magic happens, when the result is ready reenable the button and remove the load animation. Pretty common pattern I would say.

Comment: @Alejandro alright make sense.

Comment: @Riccardo You are right, I realized later about the async calls. Will prefer using isEnabled and Activity indicator where async calls are unavoidable. Thanks.

Comment: FYI: I have pages where, once ANY button has been clicked, ALL further user actions should be disabled until that button action is handled. For this, I use an instance variable `bool isBusy;` that is set at start of each button handler, and cleared (in a `finally` block) at end of handler. `void MyHandler() { if (isBusy) return; isBusy = true; try { ... } finally { isBusy = false; } }`. finally block ensures handler never fails to set isBusy back to false.